# Shell: How can I posixly determine if a file contains one or more null characters?

Tags: shell, null, posix

There are some great answers that address removing null characters from a file- it seems like sed is probably the most effective way. However, all the other questions I have been able to find are concerned not with finding null characters but removing them.

There are certain questions that do provide valid solutions- however, I am having difficulty finding a POSIX-compliant solution that does not rely on GNUisms. The two solutions I've seen that work use cat with the -v option and grep with the -P option (neither of which shall be supported).

I make it a habit to delegate as much as possible to the shell, but the shell can't help me here because it is not possible to store a null character in a variable. External tools are the only option, but I can't even find a way with them when I adhere to POSIX-compliant options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be `tr` and `wc`:

```
[ "$(tr -cd '\0' < file | wc -c)" -ge 0 ]
```

Alternatively, `od` and `grep` will allow stopping on the first one without reading the rest of the file:

```
od -A n -t x1 file | grep -q 00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tr -d '\000'`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) to trim nulls into a temporary file and use `wc -c` to get the number of characters in the file.  If the temporary-file doesn't match (`cmp -s`) the original, that contained nulls, and the output from `wc` can be used to compute the number of nulls -- the point of the question.

p.s.: [**`grep -P`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) isn't POSIX either.  Nor is the **`-C`** option found in POSIX.

Comment: Why use a temporary file?

Comment: Remove everything *except* the nulls, then replace any remaining nulls with a character you can grep for. `tr -C -d '\000' | tr '\000' a | grep -q a`.

Comment: (Actually, if there's nothing left but null bytes, `tr -Cd '\0' | grep -q .` will work.)

Comment: Why do we have to replace the null bytes by 'a'? Wouldn't it be sufficient to run `wc -c`?